# Correct way to call a product page using a static block in Magento

Tags: magento

I have a content slider setup and works correctly, but when try to add a url to the content navigation I am still seeing my placeholder (#) in the link instead of see the link. What is the correct way to call a product in a static block? I tried using something along the lines of this:

```
<ul id="nav1">
<li><input id="array_text_0" type="hidden" value="<li><a href="#"></a></li>"/></li>
<li><input id="array_text_1" type="hidden" value="<li><a href="#"></a></li>"/></li>
<li><input id="array_text_2" type="hidden" value="<li><a href="{{store direct_url='/apparel/shoes/mens/asics-men-s-gel-kayano-xii.html'}}"></a></li>"/></li>
</ul>
```

however the link does not change from (#)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have just tested with a product at `/frame.html`.  To link to that page in a static block I used `{{store direct_url="frame.html"}}` (the use of `direct_url`, instead of `url`, removes the trailing slash.)

I assume you've got caching disabled?  If not, disable it and try again.

**Edit**: There's also the fact that you've used double-quotes to wrap the arguments *and* in the value.  You'll either need to escape the double-quotes you're using as a value, or use single-quotes.

Comment: the cache is disable and been completely cleared and additionally changed the quotes, but the (#) is still showing instead of the link. where on this were you referring to change `<li><input id="array_text_2" type="hidden" value="<li><a href="{{store direct_url='/apparel/shoes/mens/asics-men-s-gel-kayano-xii.html'}}"></a></li>"/></li>`

Comment: No, I was referring to the `value` part.  You're using `value="<a href=""></a>"` where you you should be using `value="<a href=''></a>"`.

Comment: Ok I just making sure we were on the same page. But be something wrong in the cache end.